# What does Static {} mean in the Java Syntax?

Tags: java, static

I came across this Java code:

```
static {
    String aux = "value";
    try {
        // some code here
    } catch (Exception e) { }
    String UUID_prefix = aux + ":";
}
```

I am new to Java, please explain what is happening here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java ***Duplicate Thread!.***

Answer (score 47):

This is a static initialization block.  Think of it like a static version of the constructor.  Constructors are run when the class is instantiated; static initialization blocks get run when the class gets loaded.

You can use them for something like this (obviously fabricated code):

```
private static int myInt;

static {
    MyResource myResource = new MyResource();
    myInt = myResource.getIntegerValue();
    myResource.close();
}
```

See the "Static Initialization Blocks" section of [Oracle's tutorial on initializing fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 13):

This is the block of code that will get invoked when your class is loaded by  classloader

Comment: Thanks Joshi. Actually, i want to translate this code to C++. Could you explain how can i do this?

Comment: @sufyansiddique: You should come up with a new question.

Comment: WHat is there in C++ that gets executed when class is loaded just put the block of code there simply

Comment: Write a function for your class and add a a static `bool inited` field. Call the function from your ctor only if `inited` is false. Set it to true after the first call.

Answer (score 7):

This is a static initializer block. You must have found it in a class's body outside of any method. The static init block runs only once for each class, at classload time.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [static initializer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 3):

Sufyan,

Static initializers aren't inherited and are only executed once when the class is loaded and initialized by the JRE. That means this static block will be initialized only once irrespective of how many objects you have created out of this class.

I am not a big fan of it and i am sure there are better alternatives for it depending on the situation.

Thanks,
Reds

Answer (score 2):

This is called a static initialization block and will be executed once, when this class gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax has been outdated as of Java 7. Now the equivalent is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
      stuff
    */
}
```