# Java: What is the difference between <init> and <clinit>?

Tags: java, jvm

I am unable to understand the following text... Does it mean that `<clinit>` is for empty constructors? Why is important to have two different versions?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html

> ```
> 2.9. Special Methods
> ```
>
> At the level of the Java virtual machine, every constructor (§2.12) appears as an instance initialization method that has the
>   special name `<init>`. This name is supplied by a compiler. Because the
>   name `<init>` is not a valid identifier, it cannot be used directly in a
>   program written in the Java programming language. Instance
>   initialization methods may be invoked only within the Java virtual
>   machine by the invokespecial instruction, and they may be invoked only
>   on uninitialized class instances. An instance initialization method
>   takes on the access permissions (§2.7.4) of the constructor from which
>   it was derived.
>
> A class or interface has at most one class or interface initialization method and is initialized (§2.17.4) by invoking that
>   method. The initialization method of a class or interface is static
>   and takes no arguments. It has the special name `<clinit>`. This name is
>   supplied by a compiler. Because the name `<clinit>` is not a valid
>   identifier, it cannot be used directly in a program written in the
>   Java programming language. Class and interface initialization methods
>   are invoked implicitly by the Java virtual machine; they are never
>   invoked directly from any Java virtual machine inw2struction, but are
>   invoked only indirectly as part of the class initialization process.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

`<init>` is the (or one of the) constructor(s) for the instance, and non-static field initialization.

`<clinit>` are the static initialization blocks for the class, and static field initialization.

```
class X {

   static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(); // <clinit>

   private int x = 1;   // <init>

   X(){
      // <init>
   }

   static {
      // <clinit>
   }

}
```

Comment: What does `CL` stand for?

Comment: @Thilo that's interesting because the JVM treats a class definition as just yet another type of object too.

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld true, although I think there are some special rules. This method (called by class initializer) is marked as native... http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Class.java#352

Comment: @Thilo it could also stand for "ClassLoader".

Answer (score 22):

`<init>` denotes a constructor, `<clinit>` denotes a **static initializer**: ["Static Initialization Blocks" in the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), [Static initializer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java).

Answer (score 14):

The difference between `<init>` and `<clinit>` is that `<init>` is used for constructor methods that initialise an object instance, whereas `<clinit>` is used to initialise the class object itself. For instance initialisation of any `static` class level fields is done in `<clinit>` when the class is loaded and initalised.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add
If you use Class.forName method, it only intializes the class. So from within this method, it makes a call only to clinit and when you use newInstance on the object returned from forName, it will call init for the instance initialization. You can use below code to see it in debug.

```
public class ByteCodeParent
{
 public static String name="ByteCode";
 public ByteCodeParent()
{
    System.out.println("In Constructor");
}

 static
 {
     System.out.println("In Static");
 }

 {
     System.out.println("In Instance");
 }
```

To test, use

```
   Class<ByteCodeParent> bcp2 =(Class<ByteCodeParent>) Class.forName("ByteCodeParent");
ByteCodeParent bcp4= bcp2.newInstance();
```