# What is an <init> method in Java? Can it be overridden?

Tags: java, initialization

`<init>` method can be found in stacktrace, for example.
As I understood it represents initialization done in constructor.

If you try to execute

```
Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("<init>");
```

You'll get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`.

What is this method? When was it added to class? (in compilation - execution terms) Is it virtual, can one *anyhow* override it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8517121/1725096

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9), chapter 2.9. It say on the `<init>` name:

> At the level of the Java Virtual Machine, every constructor written in the Java programming language (JLS §8.8) appears as an instance initialization method that has the special name `<init>`. This name is supplied by a compiler. Because the name  is not a valid identifier, it cannot be used directly in a program written in the Java programming language.

That's why `<init>` can be found on the stack trace, but is not accessible with code.

Answer (score 8):

> What is an `<init>` method in Java?

It is a constructor.  That's why you get a `NoSuchMethodException` when you try to call it as a method.

> Can it be overriden?

No.

---

And if you see a `<clinit>` method, that is the classes static initialization "method".

Comment: +1, but `<init>` can also refer to initialization of instance fields - not just constructors.

Comment: @FabianBarney it is partially true because initialization of instance fields happens at start of every constructor.

Comment: @Pshemo Ehrm, you're right! :-)