# Reading Arabic data from Java Resource files

Tags: java

Reading Arabic data from Resource property file returns the data decoded, how can i get it without being decoded ?

tried decoding/encoding the returned value but didn't work

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages_ar","UTF-8");
value = bundle.getString(key);
URLDecoder.decode(value, "UTF-8");
```

Expected output: value to return Arabic string

Comment: Not exactly sure I understand what you're trying to do, but `.properties` files are encoded in Latin-1 in Java (call it a shortcoming). Unicode entities are escaped in there. To have unicode properties you can either use POJO-based properties, or XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from property file containing utf 8 character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755014/reading-from-property-file-containing-utf-8-character)