# Android Resources.openRawResource() encoding issue

Tags: java, android, utf-8, encode, hebrew

I have a message.properties file that contains Hebrew sentences like so:

```
loadData_fileStructureProblem=מבנה הקובץ אינו תקין
listViewer_notEnoughInformation=טיול זה לא מכיל מספיק מידע
```

Here is how I try to read from the file (an external function):

```
 public static String getMessagesValue(Context context, String name, String defaults) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    try {

        InputStream rawResource = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.messages);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(rawResource);
        return properties.getProperty(name);
```

It looks like it can find the right key-value pair but it returns a gibberish sentence like `èéåì æä ìà îëéì îñôé÷ îéãò` instead of Hebrew.

**What I've tried so far?**

I saw that there is [default encoding for .properties files in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMUJ8.png). 
The default in my program was windows-1255 so I've changed it to UTF-8 in **Setting > Editor > File encodings** but it didn't help. It's only changed the value to be like so `×ž×‘× ×” ×”×§×•×‘×¥ ××™× ×• ×ª×§×™×Ÿ`.

When I try is with English sentences as values it has no problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading from property file containing utf 8 character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755014/reading-from-property-file-containing-utf-8-character). If not make sure the file is actually encoded correctly now that you've change the encoding setting, try opening it from another editor.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. just surrounding it with new InputStreamReader(input, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't really explain it, but the problem is that `Properties.load` assumes by default that the encoding of your file is the ISO 8859-1 encoding (a subset of windows-1252), while yours was UTF-8. There's really no way of automatically "detecting" an encoding, so you have to specify it explicitly.