# JVM recursive class initialization implementation

Tags: java, jvm, language-lawyer

Am studying JVM spec/internals, and would like to understand how circularly-referenced recursive class initialization is supposed to happen correctly. Looking at this example:

```
 class CA extends Object {
    public final int ivar = 1;
    public static CB other = new CB(); 
    public CA() {
        System.out.println("in CA.init, my ivar is " + this.ivar); 
    }   
}
class CB extends Object {
    public final int ivar = 2;
    public static CA other = new CA();  
    public CB() {
        System.out.println("in CB.init, my ivar is " + this.ivar); 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CB cb = new CB();  
    }
}
```

Executing this results in:

```
in CB.init, my svar is 2
in CA.init, my ivar is 1
in CB.init, my svar is 2
```

Those reflect the instance initializations and make sense. The *class* inits though, must run like this:

1. CB `<clinit>` instantiates a CA, which should trigger...
2. CA `<clinit>`, which instantiates a CB, which attempts a
3. CB `<clinit>` again, which is already in-progress...

The JVM spec says under s5.5 Initialization:

> 3. If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by the current thread, then this must be a recursive request for initialization. Release LC and complete normally.

This implies that at my step 3 above, the JVM shrugs, and goes back to finish step 2. But completing step 2 means calling the constructor `<init>` on a new CB instance. How can it do that when class CB has not completed its `<clinit>`?

In this case, because the objects are not "doing anything" with the instances of each other they hold, no harm no foul. But how should I be thinking about the behavior and the potential pitfalls here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works because those are *static* fields (`other`), if you remove that modifier - you will get a `StackOverflow` (because for instance fields, the initialization is moved to the constructor). It seems to me that if I show you what the compiler is actually doing, things might get obvious?

```
static class CA extends Object {

    public final int ivar = 1;
    public static CB other;

    static {
        System.out.println("running CA static block");
        other = new CB();
        System.out.println("CB done");
    }

    public CA() {
        System.out.println("in CA.init, my ivar is " + ivar);
    }
}

static class CB extends Object {

    public final int ivar = 2;
    public static CA other;

    static {
        System.out.println("running CB static block");
        other = new CA();
        System.out.println("CA done");
    }

    public CB() {
        System.out.println("in CB.init, my ivar is " + ivar);
    }


}
```

**EDIT**

Messing with what instance methods are called, until the class is fully initialized is indeed dangerous. You might be stepping on things you would not expect:

```
 static class CB {

    private static final CB ONLY = new CB();

    private static final Integer IVAR = 42;
    public final int ivar = IVAR;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(CB.ONLY.ivar);
}
```

This throws a `NullPointerException`. Why? You can decompile yourself and see, but in rather simplified words:

- `ivar` is initialized in the constructor by reading the `IVAR` variable
- statics are executed in the order of how they appear in code

So, first `private static final CB ONLY = new CB();` is executed, as such, constructor must be called and thus `ivar` initialized. `ivar` is set to `IVAR`, but the latter will be initializes only *after* the constructor finishes. So when trying to set `ivar`, it will unbox the value of `IVAR`, which at this point (because `CB` is not fully initialized) is `null`.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good clarifier of how this example works--and indeed `in CB.init...` is printed before `CB done` which confirms that CB's `<clinit>` has not fully completed at a time when a instance of CB is successfully created. And again, in this case, that causes no semantic problems, but nonetheless means that instance methods (init) can be run before a class is "fully initialized". Is it fair to say that this works when it works and when there *is* a semantic conflict, it will just end up blowing up on you at runtime? (With a stack overflow or otherwise?)

Comment: @BenZotto I am not entirely sure what you mean, but does [the difference between clinit and init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517121/java-what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-clinit) helps may be?

Comment: No, I get the distinction there-- my question here is that when I run your version of the example, the constructor for CB (indicated by "in CB.init...") gets executed *before* the completion of the class initialization for CB (indicated by "CB done"). That means that it's "OK" in some circumstances to run instance methods on instances of a class before the class itself has been fully "initialized". That was a surprising consequence for me, and I want to understand if that just sort of works when it works (this case) and blows up if it doesn't.

Comment: @BenZotto I came up with an example where it breaks, hopefully this will help.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for coming up with this. It sounds like the lesson here is that there's no magic-- if the recursive initialization happens to be semantically harmless it will "work", but if you do anything that logic suggests you can't, it will just break as here. I note too that `NullPointerException` is a sort of tell for this kind of failure (since an `int` field does not take a `null` in general).

Comment: @BenZotto right. but the compiler does not know that there is a `null` coming there, so it simply compiles that with `Integer::valueOf`...

Comment: This can be really annoying with `enum` types. Since the syntax does not allow static initializers before the constants, all static fields (except compile-time constants) are initialized after the instance constructors ran, in general.