# How does a method signature of only "static" work?

Tags: java, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static initializer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java)

I have a few years' experience with Java, but I've recently run across something I've never seen before:

```
public class Project{
...
static{
  initDataTypeMapping();
}
...
}
```

How does this method signature work? Is this in fact even technically a method? I'm wondering why one wouldn't simply put the the method call to `initDataTypeMapping()` in the constructor. Just trying to increase my understanding so I don't mess something up. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as a [static initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

The code in the `static { }` block is run when the class is first loaded by the classloader (which is usually, but not always, when code that refers to the class is first loaded/executed), and is guaranteed to be run in a thread-safe manner.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java) also.

Comment: The code is only run once, right? The first time the code is referenced?