# Why final field variable can not assign to blank in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Like other variables, i want to assign final field type variable to blank but initialization is blocking by Java. What is the its logic? Maybe i want to use default values of my variables? for int = 0, string = null boolean = false etc...

```java
public class Hello {

static final int myNumber; /* it is giving "The blank final field myNumber 
                                may not have been initialized" error in Eclipse */
}
```

Comment: Because it is `final`. Use final for only those fields that you want to initialized once and thus have a constant value throughout. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement. It does not need to be initialized at the point of declaration: this is called a "blank final" variable.

change your code

```
public class Hello {

final int myNumber; 
 public Hello(int num){
 this.myNumber = num;
}

}
```

for static final variable use static block for initialization

```
static{
        myNumber = 0;
    }
```

Comment: but if leave blank the value of variable while declaration it is giving error, i can not declare it later. Maybe my Eclipse confused :)

Comment: you can initialize in later with constructor;

Comment: one more question @Mohammod Hossain. If constructor can change the value of final with every object call or creation, final (constant) variable can change. Is it very dangerous ?

Comment: How are you changing a static final in a constructor? You'd have to use a [static initializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java). This would work if myNumber weren't static.

Comment: @Perception . which compile type error are you getting in following code?

Answer (score 4):

In Java, after you use the `final` keyword with a `static` variable, you must define the value at the point of declaration. You must give it some value and stick with it.

Comment: excuse me? if i don't use the '=' i am taking error, if i use the '=' there is not problem ?

Comment: if it is static and final, you must use = at the time of declaration.

Comment: Or use a [static initializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java), but that's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2) : "It is a compile-time error if a blank final (§4.12.4) class variable is not definitely assigned (§16.8) by a static initializer (§8.7) of the class in which it is declared."

Answer (score 0):

When you use the "final" modifier with a variable, you must initialize it then as it is the only time you're allowed to use the assignment operator(you can initialize once if you left it blank) on it ("="). Like parker.sikand said, you will get an error if you try to assign a value to it afterwards.

Also, an important note that final STRICTLY means that you cannot use the assignment operator. If the object that is "final" is a mutable object then of course the contents of that object can change without ever using the assignment operator.

EDIT: I believe a final variable has to be guaranteed to be initialized at SOME point in the program which is why you generally initialize it on declaration

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 2019-09 now proposes a quickfix for that:

> ### Initialize '`final`' fields
>
> A Java quickfix is now offered to initialize an uninitialized `final` field in the class constructor.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/images/finalquickfix1.png]

> The fix will initialize a `String` to the empty string, a numeric base type to 0, and for class fields it initializes them using their default constructor if available or null if no default constructor exists.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/images/finalquickfix2.png]