# abstract class as shared memory on different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an abstract class which is inherited by classes that run on different threads. do the variables in this abstract class act as shared memory?

```
public abstract class A
{
   public abstract void foo();

   public boolean bar(){
   {
      List<String> x=new ArrayList();
      x.add("a");
      //some code
   }
}
public class B extends A
{
   @Override
   public void foo()
   {
     //some code
   }
 }
public class C extends A
{
   @Override
   public void foo()
   {
     //some code
   }
   @Override
   public boolean bar()
   {
      List<String> x=new ArrayList();
      x.add("a");
      //some code
   }
 }
public class D extends A
{
   @Override
   public void foo()
   {
     //some code
   }
 }
```

classes B, C and D run in different threads. however x is behaving like a shared memory for A and B and D. is it the expected behaviour? if yes how can i make it thread specific without overriding?

Comment: your example doesn't really show what's happening.  You're going to have to put in more detail.  What do you mean shared memory?  What do you mean by "run"?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to make `x` a field? As a local variable it will never be _shared memory_ as local variables reside on the stack.

Comment: @Seelenvirtouose: How to assign x as a field here, any clue?

Comment: @OP: see also `ThreadLocal`

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose How to make it a field? i am not able to figure out.

Comment: @VictorSorokin will look into ThreadLocal. thanks a lot.

Comment: They are your classes. I was simply trying to figure out, what you are asking. With that code (containing `x` as a method's local variable) this question does not make sense.

Comment: I will make an edit soon to make it clearer. thanks for the help and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: If you do not know "how to make [x] a field," then you probably are not ready to start messing with threads.  You need to learn more about the basics of the language.  (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: Classes are alwyas shared but they are stateless.  It is instances of class which you share state across threads.

Answer (score 0):

the `x` variable is not being shared. It's replicated on any thread that invokes the `bar()` method. If its content is always the same, you should declare it as `static final` member variable. That is:

```
public abstract class A
{
 static final  List<String> x=new ArrayList();
```

Probably it'd also be a good idea to initialize it through a static initializer: [Static initializer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java)