# Java default constructor without initialization

Tags: java, constructor, default, super

I have a class similar to the below one with all static methods. Hence the class was not initialized while used in other classes.  I have to check a condition before invoking any static methods from this class.  Even if i add a default constructor it will not get called.  Could someone suggest ideas to have solution without instantiating this class in all of its usages?  It need be a default constructor could be a simple other solution.

I need to check everytime the network connectivity before making the call. Static Initializer gets called only first time on load.

```
        public class ABCServerUtil {

        public static boolean checkServer() {...bla...bla...}


        }
```

I need some thing like below piece of code to be called and to be exit.

```
        public ABCServerUtil(){
        if(!isNetworkOnline())
        return;
        }
```

Comment: **Hence the class was not initialized while used in other classes.** - How do you know that it didn't get *initialized*? You don't have any static initializer blocks.. And please explain in detail what is happening and what isn't. :)

Comment: What you are describing is not an object and thus needs no constructor.  You are defining static behavior and thus need to program it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static Initialization block

```
static {
    //whatever code for initialization
}
```

- A class can have any number of static initialization blocks
- they can appear anywhere in the class body
- static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code.

You should be called every time when method called

```
public class Test {

    public static void checkServer() {
        if (!checkNetwork()) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public static void checkClient() {
        if (!checkNetwork()) {
            return;
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkNetwork() {
        return true; // or false depending on network condition
    }
}
```

Comment: @TheLostMind I did not see the question has been edited?

Comment: @TheLostMind ok. Now what should i do?Can i update my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check the condition **every time** one of the static methods is called, you don't have much choice but to do what you're doing: Call a method to do the check at the beginning of each of those methods.

If you only need to check the condition *once* when the class is initially loaded/initialized, you can use a [*static initializer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7):

```
public class ABCServerUtil {

    static {
        // Code here runs when the class is loaded
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: *If you need to check the condition every time one of the static methods is called,* - He could use a Proxy to call all his methods here :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static initialiser.

```
static {
    // code here
}
```

It will be run before any method of property (static or otherwise) of the class is first accessed.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly call a static method with the class name like this,

```
 boolean val=ABCServerUtil.checkServer();
```

some tutorial is given [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function/)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's already 5 answers saying the same thing and none of them seem to be what you're after:

A tool like [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/) sounds like what you need.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this is your solution: [Static initializer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java)

In practice you need a block of code executed the first time that your class is loaded.