# Spring Boot - how to war package credential files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gmail-api

I'm using the gmail API. When I war package my application, my client_secrets.json and credentials file are not inside. How do I ensure that they are available for use?

Comment: Don't package them into the executable; provide them at runtime instead.

Comment: @chrylis do you mean hosting the client_secrets.json outside the war file?

Comment: Either that or not using JSON and building the credentials object from environment variables or properties. Spring Boot configuration properties make this simple.

Comment: @chrylis If i'm running the war from tomcat on ubuntu, which directory can I point it to? (I'm not sure which directories the tomcat user is allowed access to..)

Comment: You should be able to set properties for your application in your Tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using Maven or Gradle, you need to put them into `/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json`. (not into the root folder of your project!)

Then they are 'inside' the jar.

Then you can load an pass it to `GoogleClientSecrets` like this:

```
InputStream in = XXX.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json");
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

`XXX` you should replace with your class name. Google is using the same in their quickstart. See: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java Step 3.

**Update regarding your comment:**

Everything which you place inside `/src/main/resources` is inside the "root" of your war-File. That means they are in the root of your classpath. All this stuff you can access over the classloader (**not FileInputStream**) like this:

```
XXX.class.getResourceAsStream("/folder/filename");
```

The `FileInputStream` which you mentioned you use normally only to access files outside the `war`

Your suggestion with `InputStream in = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/credentials/gmail/client_secret.json");` Does only work inside your IDE because there the folder `src/main/resources` really exists. When you package it as an `war`, as i described above, the content of `src/main/resources` is moved into the root of your `war`.

Comment: thanks! resources does package the static file.

what if I want to deploy with war? does "src/main/resources/credentials/gmail/client_secret.json" still work?

Comment: Yes in `war`-package mode `/src/main/resources` are also considered. Otherwise all your logging configuration and stuff like that would be inside the war file.  Is that was you asked?

Comment: not exactly...how do I now reference those resources? InputStream in =
          new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/credentials/gmail/client_secret.json"); 
doesn't work any more.

Comment: i updated the answer, can you check whether this makes sense for you?

Comment: makes sense, substituting stuff before I try deployment again...what do I change DATA_STORE_DIR = new File("src/main/resources/credentials/gmail"); to?

Comment: Nope, `XXX.class.getResourceAsStream("/credentials/gmail/client_secret.json");` should work inside your IDE and on production.

Comment: oh, that works, thanks! for the second variable, DATA_STORE_DIR, what do I change it to?

Comment: I am trying private static java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new File(GmailQuickstart.class.getResource("/credentials/gmail/").toURI());
but it gives an unhandled exception, can't put a throws on the class...

Comment: Stuff like this you can initialize in static constructors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java But thats not a good style of programming

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it suites you

Comment: yep thanks! it works on my local machine, but still fails on my deployed instance. I can't figure out what happened...setting logging.path = classpath:/log still doesn't output a log file :/

Comment: You can open another question for that. Give some information about your enviroment (which spring version, server, ..., log configuration)