# initializing global buffered images (Java)

Tags: java, bufferedimage

So I know to declare and initialize a global variable one would have to do something like this for example:

```
public static int Variable = 2;
```

But I want to know if there is a way to initialize a global BufferedImage variable with an image from a file. I can't use the above code, since I also need to include a try/catch statement.

Anyone have any solutions to my problem?

Comment: Use [static initializers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use a `static` bloc.

```
 public static BufferedImage image = null ;

 static
     {
     try {
         image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File("Image path")) ; // Or whatever reader you use.
         }
     catch (IOException ex)
         {
         Logger.getLogger(Prototyper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
     }
```

Btw, as mentioned in the first comment below, **this is REALLY bad practice**. Usually you want to use a Read static method, and you read the image where you need it, not by default.

Comment: Why not just use a static method? Anyway, doing I/O in static initialization is bad practice, and should be avoided. I won't downvote, as it's what the OP asked for, but.. Really, don't do this. :-)

Comment: I DO AGREE and I DO NOT DO that either, I just answered the question. I use a static method that read an image when I need it. In his case, he wants to do it by default. I've edited my answer to precise it.