# I have the following two diffetent ways of declaring an integer array in Java, one works and one doesn't, why?

Tags: java, arrays

The following is first way of declaring, and it worked:

```
static final int N = 9;
public static int[] arr = new int[N];
```

This is the one that doesn't:

```
static final int N = 9;
int arr[];    //declaring array
arr = new int[N];  // allocating memory to array
```

Eclipse gave me the error reminder on the second line that I don't quite get it:
Syntax error on token ";", , expected

Thank you for taking the time reading my question, any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: What part is not clear? The first is legal Java. The second is not legal. Specifically, `arr = new int[N];` is **not** in a constructor, method, or initialization block. Also, `int arr[]` is **not** `static` or `final` (but it isn't necessary for `arr` to be `static` or `final` in your first example).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for the advice. I learnt the second part from a tutorial website. I wonder is there any circumstance that I can use "arr = new int [N];" to declare an array?

Answer (score 5):

From the `public` keyword in your first example, I'm guessing this appears directly inside a class definition.

`arr = new int[N];` is executable code and executable code can't appear directly inside a class definition.  Depending on whether it needs to be `static`, you have to put it either inside a constructor or inside a [static initializer block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-and-a-non-static-initialization-code-blo).

Comment: Thanks! they are appearing inside a class definition, I will check out the ways you suggested to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my initial comment, you can use that syntax in an initialization block (or a constructor). Like,

```
int arr[];    //declaring array
{
    arr = new int[N];   // allocating memory to array
}
```

**or**

```
public class MyClass {
    static final int N = 9;
    int arr[];    //declaring array
    public MyClass() {
        super();
        arr = new int[N];  // allocating memory to array
    }
}
```

Note that the two examples here are actually the same in byte-code. Initialization blocks (and statements) are copied by the compiler into constructors (including the default constructor) - basically as seen here.