# How to use an array in more than one method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to create mutliple methods which all use data from the same array. The method createDeck works fine. But for the other two methods, they just return null. Is there a way to fix this?

```
class Deck
{
    private static String[] suit = {"Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts"};
    private static String[] rank = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", 
                                     "King", "Ace"};
    private static String[] deck = new String[52];

    // create deck
    static void createDeck()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
        {
            deck[i] = rank[i % 13] + " of " + suit[i / 13];
            System.out.println(deck[i]);
        }
    }

    // shuffle deck
    static void shuffleDeck()
    {
        // shuffle the deck
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
        {
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * deck.length);

            String temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[index];
            deck[index] = temp;
        }

        // print the shuffled deck
        for (String u : deck)
        {
            System.out.println(u);
        }
    }

    static void findTop()
    {
        System.out.println(deck[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: you already are using your array(s) in several methods. I don't see the issue here? How and in which order do you call them?

Comment: You need to call createDeck before you call other methods as until you do that, your deck array is filled with nulls

Comment: the other methods are ``void`` - i can't believe that they ``return null`` - what exactly is the problem? You can use the other two only after ``createDeck`` has been run.

Comment: @Grisgram she means that she gets a NPE when she tries to work with decks[i]

Comment: @Stultuske Printing null doesn't generate a NPE. Most likely OP refers to "null" being printed in the console

Comment: @JoakimDanielson idd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to directly fill the array using a *static initalizer* which gets called automatically.

Just add this code block after the decalration of the array at the beginning of the class

```
private static String[] deck = new String[52];

static {
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
    {
        deck[i] = rank[i % 13] + " of " + suit[i / 13];
        System.out.println(deck[i]);
    }
}
```

And of course remove the method `createDeck` since it is no longer needed. The following code will now be executed correctly and printing values from the array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deck.findTop();
    Deck.shuffleDeck();
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-and-a-non-static-initialization-code-blo) for more info on static initializer

Answer (score 0):

If it is used in your object, you can put the `Array` inside the constructor of an object.

```
public class Deck {
   String[] deck;
   public Deck(){  
       this.deck = new String[52];
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.